# VBA to create Outline View

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use the Web Layout View with collapsible Headings.

How to expand all headings but keep normal Text collapsed ?

this VBA Code processes 1k words in 1second .
But on longer documents ( 100k words) it just freezes.

```
Sub outline_doc2()
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.CollapseAllHeadings
    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        ' if heading is NOT normal Text , expand...
        If para.OutlineLevel <> wdOutlineLevelBodyText Then
            para.CollapsedState = False
            '... but if next paragraph is normal text , then do not expand
            If para.Next.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText Then
                para.CollapsedState = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

These changes are sensitive to the UI, so I'd recommend setting up the `ScreenUpdating` property while you are doing some work on the Word document:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' some work here
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Still the document takes way too long to process after 4 minutes I terminated the process

Comment: Consider using the Open XML SDK instead. Sometimes it improves the process if you deal with open XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

Currently using a workaround method :

1. manually indicate Headings to Expand with a "+" prefix
2. Letting an external Script iterate over the Headings and send Expand command it it matches the "+" Prefix

On a Document of 50k words , my updated VBA Script still produced no results after 4 minutes so I terminated the process.
The External Script had the Document outlined after 1:30 minutes.

App i use for this : strokesplus